# viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() is deprecated in one project and not in another. How to know the version in which a library of my project is?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am updating an old project that was abandoned. The project was created back when RecyclerView had to be implemented in the `build.gradle` file.. Today the suggestion to update appeared and I did so and therefore it was like this:

```
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.1"
```

But now I see that when I use something like `int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();` It tells me that `getAdapterPosition()` is deprecated.

I got curious because I've used `getAdapterPosition()` in many recent projects and I don't remember it being deprecated so I went to check my recent projects and it doesn't appear as deprecated in any of them.

So, going through the documentation I found that `getAdapterPosition()` has been deprecated in version 1.2.0 of RecyclerView and with this a lot of doubts arose.

How can I tell the version of a library that is not deployed from the `build.gradle`? I'm assuming that if my new projects don't get the deprecated method warning, it's because they're using an older version of the RecyclerView library. But if this is correct then why are they using an old version? isn't Android supposed to implement the latest version?

Finally, I have removed `implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.1"` from the project that I am updating and the deprecation problem is gone. In these situations what is better to do? Let Android do things or implement each library in `build.gradle`?

Comment: Replacement is [`bindingAdapterPosition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getBindingAdapterPosition()) or `absoluteAdapterPosition`. Personally I'm a bit baffled they decided to alter `ViewHolder` implementation with such deprecation since those two methods return identical value unless you're using a specific subclass of `RecyclerView.Adapter`  - [`ConcatAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ConcatAdapter).